# Running Traefik docker-proxy behind an apache server, redirecting/proxying some of the requests (or vice versa)

Tags: linux, docker, apache, proxy, traefik

I have a Traefik-2 docker-compose-setup for dev (and one similar for prod) with multiple docker-compose projects containing multiple dc-images, each can be reached locally like this: https://docker-app1.docker-doamin1.loc, incl. HTTPS/SSL-Certs; "dns" via /etc/hosts.

This works like a charm, when the traefik-container is running and the apache is not (port conflict otherwise)

I also have some projects that can be run directly on a local apache (on ubuntu/debian) with configurations in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apache-app1.apache-domain1.loc

    DocumentRoot /path-to/apache-app1.apache-domain1.loc/public
    <Directory /path-to/apache-app1.apache-domain1.loc/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
            Fallbackresource /index.php
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    
</VirtualHost>
```

But only if the apache is running and the docker-traefik container ist not, again because of the conflicting 80/443

I need (or want) both Versions to run simultaneously.

My idea was to run the docker-traefik container on different ports (20080/20443) and redirect/ProxyPass from apache to that docker-proxy-container (the other way round would be okay too)

I tried (e.g.)this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName docker-app1.docker-doamin1.loc
  ServerAlias www.https://docker-app1.docker-doamin1.loc
  ProxyPass / https://docker-app1.docker-doamin1.loc:20443/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://docker-app1.docker-doamin1.loc:20443/
</VirtualHost>
```

having

```
127.0.1.1 docker-app1.docker-doamin1.loc
```

in my /etc/hosts.

But it does not work. And it would be better in each case to have wildcards redirected like this: `*.docker-doamin1.loc`.

For now all of this is for a local dev environment, so security is not that relevant.

It would be great, if someone had some hints here.

Answer (score 0):

we do it with Proxy*:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
  ServerName ...
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyAddHeaders On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8089/ connectiontimeout=28800 timeout=28800 Keepalive=On nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8089/
</VirtualHost>
```

You've an error in your ServerAlias:

```
ServerAlias www.https://docker-app1.docker-doamin1.loc
```

I think you mean:

```
ServerAlias www.docker-app1.docker-doamin1.loc
```